Minimun gap between closed linear subspaces is symmetric in Hilbert spaces

Suppose $M,N$ are two closed subspaces of a Hilbert space. We define the minimum gap between these two subspaces by
$$
\gamma(M,N):=\inf_{u\in M\backslash N}\frac{\mathrm{dist}(u,N)}{\mathrm{dist}(u,M\cap N)}.
$$
Prove that $\gamma(M,N)=\gamma(N,M)$.

In the book Perturbation theory for linear operators, Kato mentioned in a footnote that this follows from the equality $||1-P||=||P||$ where $P$ is an orthogonal projection. But I couldn't see why.

What have you tried? Remember that in a Hilbert space you can express the distance between a vector and a closed subspace using the orthogonal projection tied to said closed subspace. Another thing to note is that the last equality you mention is not true for $P = 0$ or $I$, so you might want to re-look at the aforementioned footnote?

Some of what you have written in your question does not match up with what is mentioned in Kato's book. A reformulation of what is stated in his book is as follows.
Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $M$ and $N$ be closed subspaces of $X$. Define
\begin{equation}
\gamma (M,N) := \begin{cases} \displaystyle\inf_{u\in M\setminus N} \frac{{\rm dist}(u, N) }{{\rm dist}(u, M\cap N)} & \text{if} \; M \not\subseteq N, \\ 1 & \text{if} \; M\subseteq N. \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then $\hat{\gamma}(M,N) := \min \{ \gamma (M,N), \gamma (N,M) \}$ is defined to be the minimum gap between $M$ and $N$. This definition does not depend on the order of $M$ and $N$.
The book states that given closed subspaces $M$ and $N$ it follows that $\gamma (M,N)$ is not symmetric with respect to $M$ and $N$, or in other words it is not always the case that $\gamma (M,N) = \gamma (N,M)$. This is why $\hat{\gamma }(M,N)$ is introduced. However, if $X$ is a Hilbert space then the result is true.
To prove the desired result, you can use and modify the proof in Chapter Four, Theorem 4.2. which is stated below (under the assumption that the underlying space is a Banach space) for completeness.

Theorem 4.2. In order that $M+N$ be closed, it is necessary and sufficient that $\gamma (M,N) > 0$.

Let $H$ be the underlying Hilbert space. If $M+N$ is not closed in $H$ then by Theorem 4.2. you have that $\gamma (M,N) = \gamma (N,M) = 0$.
Otherwise, suppose $M+N$ is closed in $H$. If $M = \{0\}$ or $N = \{0\}$ then $M\subseteq N$ or $N\subseteq M$ respectively and it is readily seen that $\gamma (M,N) = \gamma (N,M) = 1$. If $M\neq \{0\}$ and $N\neq \{0\}$ then let $P$ be the orthogonal projection of $M+N$ onto $M$ along $N$. Then
\begin{align*}
\|P\| &= \sup_{u\in (M+N)\setminus\{0\} } \frac{\|Pu\| }{\|u\| } = \sup_{\substack{v\in M, \, w\in N, \\ v+w \neq 0} } \frac{\|v\| }{\|v+w\| } = \sup_{v\in M\setminus\{0\}, \, w\in N} \frac{\|v\| }{\|v+w\| } \\
&= \sup_{v\in M\setminus\{0\} } \frac{\|v\| }{{\rm dist}(v, N) } = \sup_{v\in M\setminus N } \frac{{\rm dist}(v, M\cap N) }{{\rm dist}(v, N) }.
\end{align*}
Since $\|P\| > 0$ because $M\neq \{0\}$ it follows that
\begin{equation}
\gamma (M,N) = \inf_{u\in M\setminus N} \frac{{\rm dist}(u, N) }{{\rm dist}(u, M\cap N)} = \left( \sup_{v\in M\setminus N } \frac{{\rm dist}(v, M\cap N) }{{\rm dist}(v, N) } \right)^{-1} = \|P\|^{-1}.
\end{equation}
Analogously it can be shown using $N \neq \{0\}$ that $\gamma (N,M) = \|I-P\|^{-1}$. It then follows from $\|P\| = \|I-P\|$ that
\begin{equation}
\gamma (M,N) = \|P\|^{-1} = \|I-P\|^{-1} = \gamma (N,M).
\end{equation}
Hence you have $\gamma (M,N) = \gamma (N,M)$ whenever $M+N$ is closed in $H$ and $M\cap N = \{0\}$.
For the general case, suppose $M+N$ is closed in $H$. Define $X := H / (M\cap N)$. The quotient space $X$ is a Hilbert space because $M\cap N$ is a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $H$. Let $\pi : H\to X$ be the natural quotient map and define both $\widetilde{M} := \pi (M)$ and $\widetilde{N} := \pi (N)$. Then $\pi^{-1}(\widetilde{M}) = \pi^{-1}(\pi (M)) = M$ is closed in $H$ and so $\widetilde{M}$ is a closed subspace of $X$. Similarly, $\widetilde{N}$ is a closed subspace of $X$. Since
\begin{equation}
\pi^{-1}(\widetilde{M} \cap \widetilde{N}) = \pi^{-1}(\widetilde{M}) \cap \pi^{-1}(\widetilde{N}) = M\cap N = {\rm ker} \, \pi \tag{1}
\end{equation}
it follows by applying $\pi$ to both sides of (1) that $\widetilde{M} \cap \widetilde{N} = \{0\}$. Furthermore, since $\pi (M+N) = \widetilde{M} + \widetilde{N}$ and as $\pi^{-1}(\pi (M+N)) = M+N$ is closed in $H$, it follows that $\widetilde{M} + \widetilde{N}$ is closed in $X$. Hence the preceding paragraph can be applied to deduce that $\gamma (\widetilde{M}, \widetilde{N}) = \gamma (\widetilde{N}, \widetilde{M})$.
Let $u\in H$. Then
\begin{equation}
{\rm dist}(\pi (u), \widetilde{M}) = \inf_{v\in M} \|\pi (u) - \pi (v)\| = \inf_{v\in M} \inf_{x\in M\cap N} \|(u-v) - x\| = \inf_{v\in M} \|u-v\| = {\rm dist}(u, M).
\end{equation}
Similarly it is shown that $u\in H$ implies ${\rm dist}(\pi (u), \widetilde{N}) = {\rm dist}(u, N)$ and ${\rm dist}(\pi (u), \widetilde{M}\cap \widetilde{N}) = {\rm dist}(u, M\cap N)$. These identities imply
\begin{equation}
\gamma (\widetilde{M}, \widetilde{N}) = \gamma (M,N) \; \text{and} \; \gamma (\widetilde{N}, \widetilde{M}) = \gamma (N,M)
\end{equation}
from which follows $\gamma (M,N) = \gamma (N,M)$ as desired.
